# Am I able to clone and merge files in perforce at once?

Tags: perforce, p4v

So my problem began when I've cloned a repo from shared server, made some changes and few submits. Then I closed p4v and opened it again. My workspace disappeared but only from perforce view(I still have local changes). And there are no changes on the server. So my question is: am I able to clone repo to the path full of changes without losing them, or at least can I do something to avoid downloading whole repo again.

Greetings and thanks for your time. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are using DVCS (a personal server on your computer) of if you ran 'p4 sync' to get the files in to your workspace. If using DVCS, 'p4 fetch' or 'p4 fetch -t' will enable you to pull in any changes from the server. If you simply synced the files to your local machine, then you can simply sync any changes. If changes have occurred on the server, you will need to resolve them before submitting. You will be prompted to do this when you try to submit your changelist.b